# Sum of two date objects

Tags: java

```
ArrayList<WayRegisterBean> subList=new ArrayList<WayRegisterBean>();
Object[] obj1=(Object[])atItr1.next();
String s1Fxxno=(String)obj1[0];
int s1Docno=(Integer)obj1[1];
Date s1From=(Date)obj1[2];
Date s1To=(Date)obj1[3];
String s1Trans=(String)obj1[4];
String s1Bilamt=(String)obj1[5];
int s1Pcode=(Integer)obj1[6];
to=s1From + s1To;
```

please  help  i am trying to add two dates  like s1From + s1To but do not know how to add it so please help

Thanks in advance

Comment: What does it mean to sum two dates?

Comment: The original title said something about hibernate. I removed that tag because, as written now, it has nothing to do with hibernate. If "hibernate criteria" was relevant to the question, please add more detail to explain how.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Date object , you can try below.

```
Date s1From=(Date)obj1[2]; 
Date s1To=(Date)obj1[3];  
long sum = s1From.getTime() + s1To.getTime(); 
Date sumDate = new Date(sum);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the desired result by adding :

```
long toLongDate = s1From.getTime() + s1To.getTime();

to = new Date(toLongDate);
```

Hope this works.

Answer (score 0):

Use `getTime()` method with **returns the long value, dating back from January 1st 1970, to the date in the Date Object.**

```
Date s1From=(Date)obj1[2]; 
Date s1To=(Date)obj1[3]; 

long totalDate = s1From.getTime() + s1To.getTime();

Date d = new Date(totalDate);
```

You can alternatively use `setTime()` method, like this..

```
Date d = new Date();
d.setTime(totalDate);
```